# Different behavior of queries - dependent on environment

Tags: php, sql-server

I know, it is a wide question, I just need some hints to solve it.
I wrote some kind of WebApp, using HTML, PHP, SQLSRV (MS SQL Server Express) to collect data from our daily visits at a hospital.

All works fine on my Laptop at home, you can add patients, view details, move them to an archive and so on. HomeEnvironment is PHP 5.6.3, MS-SQL Server 2012 Express. As soon as I copy my *.php - Files onto the network at my company, all screws up: dates aren't sorted right way, some queries work, some doesn't, Buttons disappear - and I have no clue, why this happens. It is - as far as I know - the same environment (besides "full" SQL Server 2012), PHP-Version is same.

I know you can't find a solution, but it would be great, if anyone could give me a hint, where to look for a mistake or where to start troubleshooting. Or if anyone experienced the same and could find a solution.
If any code is needed, feel free to ask!

Comment: "if anyone could give me a hint" your error log is your best friend in such a situation.

Comment: Backup the httpd.conf of the Apache of your company, then replace the original with httpd.conf from your Home Environment. 
Restart Apache and show us what result was written in the Apache log.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - replacement won't be possible =(. It is a hospital, containing over 1000 patients, multiple databases, and my App is just for a small group of people there. But how can I write @php to write an ErrorLog I can read afterwards? I really dont know how to do this.